# Read gzip file from iOS web service call

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, gzip

I have an iOS app where I use `NSURLConnection` to fetch some data. When I print the headers from the response, this is what I see:

```
"Content-Disposition" = "attachment;filename=test.txt.gz";
"Content-Encoding" = agzip;
"Content-Type" = "application/a-gzip";
Date = "Mon, 05 Nov 2012 22:18:23 GMT";
Server = "Apache-Coyote/1.1";
"Set-Cookie" = "JSESSIONID=3EBBF519202E16BEB1E79D12XXXXXXXXX; Path=/";
"Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
filename = "test.txt.gz";
```

But, when I try to read the log the text file like this:

```
NSString *result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:myData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",result);
```

I get `null`. I know the data is there because it spits out hex when I log it, and I know the call works because I have tested it in RESTClient. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using ASIHTTPRequest, it handles this seamlessly. http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

Comment: Only problem is that ASIHTTPRequest has stopped all work (last update was May 2011) and the site recommends NOT using for new projects...

Answer (score 0):

If it's gzipped data, then it's not NSUTF8StringEncoded. Unzip your data before you try and convert it.  (given that it really is a string after unzipping)